# NativeScript GridLayout Alignment Problem - iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to make it so I have the MENU label on the far left of the `ActionBar` and the logo in the center, for iOS.

```
<template>
  <ActionBar>
    <GridLayout backgroundColor="green" columns="*, *" rows="*, *">
      <Label v-if="isIos" row="0" col="0" text="MENU" @tap="openDrawer()" class="c-actionbar_label_ios"/>
      <Image v-if="isIos" row="0" col="1" @tap="goToHome()" src="~/assets/images/sklar-logo.png" class="c-actionbar_logo"/>
    </GridLayout>
  </ActionBar>
</template>
```

The problem is that GridLayout stays right in the center and doesn't stretch the full width. I was thinking `*,*` meant two columns 50% width each, but that must not be the case. I put a green background on it so you can see the current width.

[image]

Is there some way to do accomplish this layout with `GridLayout` or any other layout? I've messed with FlexBoxLayout also, but can't get that to do what I want because you cant use % widths.

Comment: [This doc](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar) might offer some advice. `ActionBar` has some alignment things going on, so your `GridLayout` isn't taking the full width of the screen.

Comment: I usually set `width="100%"` on the `<GridLayout>` that's usually enough to make it stretch to full width and then the columns work fine.

Comment: @IgorR.That does work to make it 100% width, however, now they end up on the far left and far right. So, the ```<Label>``` is where it's supposed to be but the ```<Image>``` is not. I've tried using alingment properties, like ```horizontalAlignment``` and ```textAlign``` but I can't get anything to work. This is beyond frustrating for something that should be so utterly simple.

Comment: Indeed it's utterly simple, you just have to understand the basics of native layouts. There are different elements for each purpose. You should set the background to green if you want whole ActionBar to be green. Use ActionItem with left / right positions (with custom view only if required). The custom view you put directly under ActionBar is interpreted as title view, so just the image would go there.